# Firebase messaging, message not recieved

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

My cloud function states it has sent a message successfully `undefined messages were sent successfully` but I don't receive it:

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");

var serviceAccount = require("./config.json");

admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
    databaseURL: "https://pushmessage-bd1eb.firebaseio.com"
});

const messaging = admin.messaging();
const message = {
            data: { title: "Testing", body: "Test" },
            token:
                "fm8hZocb9X0:APA91bGANY8U1k7iXSAofh8PEtyA3SfkAvyvicjHbSzDC7s1DwzhCxBBhj5oeAhiZpNLFC1wUHOPX_C0vlGtUMv882EXxBjsM4qeBpFndka8kzir9kgmJnuPTRImx2cxUT53oXzJuAzB"
        };

        messaging.send(message).then(response => {
            console.log(
                response.successCount + " messages were sent successfully"
            );
        });
```

If I use the same token in the firebase dashboard to send a message, the message sends successfully.

How can I get my cloud function to send a message?

config.json:

```
{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "pushmessage-bd1eb",
  "private_key_id": "xxx",
  "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nxxx-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
  "client_email": "firebase-adminsdk-8dd2o@pushmessage-bd1eb.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "client_id": "xxx",
  "senderID": "388436954224",
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/firebase-adminsdk-8dd2o%40pushmessage-bd1eb.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using admin.messaging().send()?

See:

- https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.messaging.Messaging#send
- https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.messaging.Message
- https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.messaging.Notification

Please try the following code.

Change `data` to `notification`.

And the admin.messaging().send() return string.

```
      const message = {
        notification: { title: "Testing", body: "Test" },
        token:
            "The registration token here"
      };

      admin.messaging().send(message).then(response => {
        console.log(
            response + " messages were sent successfully"
        );
      });
```

Or you can use admin.messaging().sendToDevice().

See:

- https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.messaging.Messaging#sendToDevice
- https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.messaging.MessagingPayload
- https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.messaging.MessagingDevicesResponse

Please try the following code.

```
      const token= "The registration token here";
      const payload = {
        notification: { title: "Testing", body: "Test" }
      };

      admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token, payload).then(response => {
        console.log(
            response.successCount + " messages were sent successfully"
        );
      });
```

Comment: Yes I am using admin.messaging, I get the error, UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: Requested entity was not found.